# SqlServer can't handle multiply queries

Tags: java, c#, mysql, sql-server, parallel-processing

I'm seeing a huge slow down when doing load testing on my app.
I have a query that takes about 350ms to run, but what I run it in parallel 8 times (not to mention 32 times), it goes up to 2.5 seconds.

I verified on a profiler that the execution is really what that is taking up the time.

the query:

```
SELECT SUM([_Facts_].[Sales]) [_measures___Sum Sales_], [_Date_].[year] [_Date___year_]
FROM [pp].[Facts] [_Facts_], [pp].[Date] [_Date_]
WHERE [_Facts_].[dateKey] = [_Date_].[dateKey]
GROUP BY [_Date_].[year]
ORDER BY [_Date_].[year] ASC
```

I'm running 8 parallel processes that make 10 calls in sequence.
For 1 parallel I get:

```
360, 350, 345, 360, 365, 360, 395, 786, 395, 370, avg:408
```

For 8 parallel:

```
515, 1571, 1471, 1326, 1862, 2478, 1922, 3098, 2413, 2032, 2773, 3048, 2453, 2092, 2077, 3359, 2898, 2733, 3018, 2483, 1887, 3023, 3088, 3724, 2317, 2753, 2643, 3284, 3299, 2418, 1907, 1862, 2498, 2838, 2518, 3203, 2613, 2207, 3434, 2613, 3198, 2257, 2593, 2448, 2518, 2968, 2828, 2122, 2963, 2212, 3299, 2988, 3153, 2803, 2157, 2543, 2758, 2998, 2538, 2257, 2788, 2443, 2082, 2613, 3173, 4205, 2603, 2387, 1747, 3854, 3068, 2788,  2603, 3103, 2703, 3198, 1832, 1421, 2217, 1326
```

avg:

```
2535, 2523, 2571, 2627, 2689, 2469, 2521, 2610
```

When going to 16 in parallel it went up to even more.

I tried testing on MySql and got the same jump (different test times, but at least 4 times slower when parallel).

Can't these DBs handle the load?!

This happens both in C# and Java:
C#:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 8, i => run());
    }

    static void run()
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=;User ID=;Password="))
        {
            conn.Open();

            var cnt = 10;

            long avg = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
            {
                var sw = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SET ARITHABORT ON", conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandText =
                        "SELECT SUM([_Facts_].[Sales]) [_measures___Sum Sales_], [_Date_].[year] [_Date___year_]\n" +
                        "FROM [pp].[Facts] [_Facts_], [pp].[Date] [_Date_]\n" +
                        "WHERE [_Facts_].[dateKey] = [_Date_].[dateKey] \n" +
                        "GROUP BY [_Date_].[year]\n" +
                        "ORDER BY [_Date_].[year] ASC";

                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        var x = 0;
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            x++;
                        }

                        reader.Close();
                    }

                }

                var dif = (DateTime.Now.Ticks - sw) / 1000;
                avg += dif;
                Console.WriteLine(dif);
            }

            conn.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("avg:" + avg / cnt);
        }
    }
}
```

Java:

```
@Test
public void asdf() throws SQLException {

   Runnable r = () -> {
      try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://;databaseName=", "", "")) {

         long avg = 0;

         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            try (Statement statement = conn.createStatement()) {
               StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
               sw.start();

               ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT SUM([_Facts_].[Sales]) [_measures___Sum Sales_], [_Date_].[year] [_Date___year_]\n" +
                     "FROM [pp].[Facts] [_Facts_], [pp].[Date] [_Date_]\n" +
                     "WHERE [_Facts_].[dateKey] = [_Date_].[dateKey] \n" +
                     "GROUP BY [_Date_].[year]\n" +
                     "ORDER BY [_Date_].[year] ASC");

               int x = 0;
               while (resultSet.next()) {
                  x++;
               }

               sw.stop();
               avg+=sw.getTime();
               System.out.println(sw);
            }
         }

         System.out.println(avg/10);

      } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {

      }
   };



   ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      executor.execute(r);
   }


   try {
      executor.shutdown();
      executor.awaitTermination(12312313, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

**MORE INFO**

The 2 tables are ~1,000 rows and ~420,000 rows. The join is ~420,000 rows and the result it 3 rows.

There is a PK on date.dateKey and FK on facts. These are tables, not views.

I checked with profiler to verify that the duration is the actual execution time of the query, and not the app's run-time.

The SqlServer has 16 cores, so I would hope for the 8 queries to run in parallel and not stack up.

On the server, CPU for 1 query goes up to 50%. for 8 it gets to 95%.

network/memory/IO doesn't seem to change dramatically.

[image: plan]

Comment: In Java, `DriverManager.getConnection` might or might not return the same Connection, leading to use the same transaction for multiple threads. You should check if the instance are different. Using a Connection Pool would reduce the risk (or remove it completly)

Comment: rather than inner query, use store procedure for this which give better performance

Comment: @AxelH I'm indeed getting different connections. In the actual app (this code is a side-test) I am using a pool, btw.

Comment: @AxelH What are you basing that on? I don't see any indication that `DriverManager` is allowed to return the same connection. The `Driver` could of course do that, but I suspect that would go against the JDBC spec.

Comment: 1. When monitoring the DB I can see the connections getting opened and closed (not re-used). 2. I checked that the objects of the connections are not the same instance. do you have another test I could check this?

Comment: @ImbarM. There's no need to check for anything. AxelH just mistakenly assumed that a connection could be shared like that.

Comment: oh ok... @Ajay2707 store procedure would be tricky because the queries are dynamic. I'm testing with the same query but the queries will be completely different each time (not even the same tables...)

Comment: "Can't these DBs handle the load?". They sure can. However if your DB schema is not optimal and you end up with a bad execution plan, you can get bad performance. The problem is on the DB side, not code. I suggest you analyze the plan for the query and see if there are any issues with it.

Comment: @Kayaman well I simply stated the possibility since there is nothing saying the opposite either ;) It could depends on the implementation of the jdbc. (Having bad connection right now, but I had found a post on SO talking about this on multithreading and JDBC, but without real evidence of either)

Comment: @AxelH Well it's not a very good idea to state hypothetical situations without any proof to back it up. It just sends people on wild goose chases.

Comment: Since you are using inline query,so execution plan is not being generated so each time your query is parse completly.Second thing we have to know table structure and data type,since you are using group by order by etc.if you write the same query in proc ,performance will improve.